# Remove characters other than alphanumeric from first 4 values of string Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove characters other than alphanumeric from first 4 characters of string. I figured out how to do it for the whole string but not sure how to process only the first 4 values.

```
Data : '1/5AN 4/41 45'

Expected: '15AN 4/41 45'
```

Here is the code to remove the non-alphanumeric characters from string.

```
strValue = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', strValue)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string slicing is one possibility:

```py
import re

strValue = '1/5AN 4/41 45'
strValue = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', strValue[:4]) + strValue[4:]

print(strValue)
```

Outputs: `15AN 4/41 45`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `isalnum()` and concatenate string

```
''.join([x for x in Data[0:4] if x.isalnum()]) + Data[4:]
#output 
'15AN 4/41 45'
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove non-alphanumeric characters in python use this:

```
import re                                                                     
string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", string)
```

`re` means regex/regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). But the question was to remove the non-alphanumeric characters from the first 4 values of string.